# How to imitate PHP's sorting of associative array in Java?

Tags: java, php, arrays

I have a PHP code:

```
$array['cows'] = 4;
$array['horses'] = 7;
$array['cats'] = 9;
$array['dogs'] = 2;

arsort($array);
```

How to do it in Java?

Sorted (from max) output of 'print_r($array);' is:

```
Array
(
    [cats] => 9
    [horses] => 7
    [cows] => 4
    [dogs] => 2
)
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

For PHP associative array you should use Map type in Java (HashMap or TreeMap). Sorting of this types described in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Comment: Sorting maps by value is not a fun exercise.  I would suggest extracting the entry set and sorting it using a comparator that looks at the entry value.

Comment: I agree with you, but it's the closest analog to PHP function